# How to let the users style a web component with their own CSS?

Tags: css, web-component

I know we can use CSS to style elements of a web component. But how can I allow the user style my web component?

For example let's say I'm making a video player but I want the people who use my component be able to set the play button or the progress bar to the color of their brands. The **[shadow boundary](http://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/)** seems to prevent it for good. But what if I want it?

It would be great if the users don't have to use attributes for such styling tasks. Standard CSS would be great but I'm not sure if it's possible as of late January 2015?

Comment: do you mean like if you have input textbox, they can determine the background color of that textbox and the font color and such?

Comment: Without knowing what back end you're on and how you'd store such information, the question is far too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ability to polyfill the requested functionality among browsers not supporting ShadowDOM natively. This is to be achieved by using `shim-shadowdom` directive within style declaration:

```
  <style shim-shadowdom>
    #mine::shadow .classname { width: 100px; background: red; }
    #mine /deep/ .classname { width: 200px; background: blue; }
  </style>
```

The first one is propagated one level below shadow host, the latter is applied to everything nested.

This live preview explores all the possibilities: http://plnkr.co/edit/rdSukYbEnPHQAphiwIG9?p=preview

Please note, that FF currently applies styles to nested shadowed elements, so everything should be re-checked twice. That said, FF fills the third nested tab with yellow color, which is generally wrong.

Further reading: http://robdodson.me/shadow-dom-css-cheat-sheet/

Comment: But what if I want my users to write clean and understandable CSS? This might sound crazy, but I am curious to know if there's a standard on the way to allow defining custom CSS properties for styling custom elements of Web Components. For example in a menu Web Component, I want to be able to let the user set the menu separator colors with a CSS rule that reads like `{separator: red}` instead of `#mine::shadow .separator { border-bottom: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: Well, you might take a look at how polyfill is implemented for `<style shim-shadowdom>` and enchance it’s behaviour. Unfortunately, AFAIK, there is no working solution for what you want at the moment.